# iOS UITextView Large Text Invisible

Tags: ios, text

I have a UITextView if my text content exceeds about 35000 characters, my Text goes invisible.
I can still select it and my Textbox has the required size to fit the text. The text exceeds the screen but is scrollable, this works for both cases but if i go above ~35000 the text just goes invisible.

When i press "Look Up" my text is actually displayed in the browser bar. Is this a Limitation of the Framework?

[image]